# How to do multiple things in a Haskell function?

Tags: haskell

I was wondering, how can we do multiple things in a Haskell function?

For example, I have this code:

```hs
number = 0

increment :: Int -> Int
increment i = i + 1

function :: String -> String
function s = s ++ " world" AND increment number
```

I was wondering, how can we do something like this? I'm searching everywhere but I don't find a solution for this simple example :O

```hs
number
0

:function "hello"
"hello world" (AND the number = 1 now)

number
1
```

*note:* I know that `AND` is not a syntax in Haskell but I wanted to make you understand what I wanted to say :)

Comment: you can take 2 parameters (or a tuple of two) and return the modified parameters as a tuple. Would this solve the issue you are facing?

Comment: You may be missing the point. The whole idea behind Haskell is that variables *don't* change. When you said `number = 0`, you swore to the compiler, now and forevermore, that *that* `number` was zero. Nothing is going to change that. That's the way the language works.

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify variables in Haskell (they are not, in fact, *variable*). What you can do is return new values:

```
f (string, number) = (string ++ " world", number + 1)
```

which would be used like this:

```
Prelude> f ("hello", 0)
("hello world",1)
```

If you called this function with a variable instead of a literal, it would not change the value of that variable, because Haskell is designed to *prevent* that from happening:

```
Prelude> let n = 0
Prelude> f ("hello", n)
("hello world",1)
Prelude> print n
0
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is: in haskell you don't have "mutable states" like in other programming languages: so "number = 1" wouldn't work in terms of "setting a State"

you could combine them as a result:

```
increment :: Int -> Int
increment i = i + 1 

stringCombine :: String -> String
stringcombine str = str ++ "world"

combine i str = (increment i, stringCombine str)
```

or if you have a function with a side effect (like print, putStrLn) you have to use the IO Monad:

```
doSideEffects :: Int -> String -> IO Int
doSideEffects i str = do
   putStrLn $ str ++ "world"
   return $ increment i
```